# unable to find while loops behavior in java

Tags: java, sockets

In my application, I have used two while loops for reading the sockets. while loop-1 takes 1% of CPU and while loop-2 takes 100% CPU. I am confused. Please share your valuable thoughts. For more information, I have added two while loops below:

**While loop-1:**

```
 while(true) {
    String message = onReadFinal(in);
    if (message != null) {
        synchronized (message) {
            System.out.println("Message size:" + message);
        }
      }
 }

 private String onReadFinal(DataInputStream in) {
    String mess = null;
    try{
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

        do {
            builder.append(in.readInt());
        } while(in.available() > 0);

        mess = builder.toString();
    } catch(IOException e){ e.printStackTrace(); }
    return mess;
 }
```

**While loop-2:**

```
 while(true) {
    String message = onRead(in);
    if (message != null) {
       synchronized (message) {
          System.out.println("Message size:" + message);
       }
    }
 }

 public String onRead(DataInputStream input) {
    String socketmessage = null;
    int length;

    try {
       if(input != null) {
          length = input.available();
          if(length>0) {
             byte[] message = new byte[length];
             input.readFully(message, 0, message.length);
             socketmessage = new String(message);
          }
       }
    } catch (IOException ioException) {
        ioException.printStackTrace(); 
    }
    return socketmessage;                    
}
```

Also, if I execute infinite while loop with no statements, it takes 100% of CPU. Someone can you please explain.

Comment: Thank you. Updated the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if a loop does not contain blocking operations, it always would take 100% CPU.

Your first loop contains blocking operation `in.readInt()`. Your second loop also contains potentially blocking operation `input.readFully()`, but calls it only when  the stream buffer has enough bytes to read, and so in fact this operation does not block. When there is not enough bytes, the loop immediately repeats non-blocking operation `input.available()`, without much sense.

You better tell us what you want.